# Why can docker not access an endpoint that the VM has access to?

Tags: docker

I have a container on my machine. My machine can access xxx.net, but the container can't unless I start it like this:

```
docker run --add-host xxx.net:192.xxx.xxx.x -p 8080:8080 -d image_id
```

or enter the container and add in the /etc/hosts file this line:

```
192.xxx.xxx.x xxx.net
```

Now, this would not be a problem if this address (192.xxx.xxx.x) would not change, but unfortunately, it does.

Can something be done about it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's because in order to access the VM you are using port 8080. When you start docker on your machine, you need to expose whatever ports you have to use. Think of it this way, if your docker container was a ship. And there was water in the ship how would you get rid of it? You would need to expose a port from the ship to the sea cause to begin with no ports are exposed. So you can't connect to your `VM because it doesn't have a port to access it by.

What you can try doing, is pass your hostname in, and edit the file from within the Dockerfile? So when your docker is created, it already has the host in `/etc/hosts`

EDIT: If the address is changing, what platform is this? If using a cloud platform, you could reserve a static IP-address for this service?

I have a similar issue when using Filestore. If restarted, the IP would change. What I then did was query the API to get the IP address, since it was the only filestore in my GCP Project, it wasn't too bad.

What IP address is this? As in, what service, on what platform. Is there anyway for you to get the IP address without manually getting it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing some details here

What is xxx.net? does the host sees that address because it is resolved by the DNS or it's a local service in other computer in the NAT? I assume the latter (the container should have access to the host DNS) so try running the docker with --network=host and see if that's help (it will share the same network with the host)

Comment: it's a local service. I tried --network=host, but it still does not work. It works only if I add --add-host xxx.net:192.xxx.xxx.x

Comment: how about docker run --add-host xxx.net:$(getent hosts xxx.net | awk '{ print $1 }' | head -n 1) -p 8080:8080 -d image_id ?

Comment: it works, but will it still work if the address(192.xxx.xxx.x) changes?

Comment: Of course, as it queries the address in the host side in every docker run.

Comment: but if the container already runs and the address changes, I will have to rerun the container. Or am I wrong?